Looking for a plugin about 3D generator from Sketch or Picture-and Texture generator
I am looking for a plugin compatible Blender to convert a picture, Sketch or Blueprint on 3D Mesh, and with possibility to edit to improve the design. I am open for Plugin with or without AI.
Can you too recommend me a plugin for Texture generator too.
Thank you in advance for your help
